# Dynamic abstract class inside abstract class

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance, abstract

I have a problem with this class construct. I want to somehow give the Extended class type of the superclass Super2 as parameter inside the Constructor of Super1, but I don't know how.

I want to meet these requirements:

- Initialize the instance of extended class of Super2 inside doStuffWithDoStuff()
- Don't add a parameter with an instance of Super2 to doStuffWithDoStuff()

```
abstract class Super2 {
    Super2(String test) {
    }
    public void exit() {
    }
}
abstract class Super1 {
    abstract doStuff(Class<? extends Super2> super);
    protected doStuffWithDoStuff() {
         Super2 super2 = new Super2("test");
         doStuff(super2);
         super2.exit();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Test1 extends Super2 {
    Test1() {
        super();
    }
    public void doStuff() {
    }
}
class Test2 extends Super1 {
    doStuff(Test1 test) {
        test.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition for `Super3`? Is it a typo?

Comment: You can't directly instantiate an abstract class, you must instantiate it through instantiating a subclass.  Super2 super = new Super2("test"); won't work, you might use an anonymous inner class.
also: Super1 extends Super3, while you don't have a Super3 class ..

Comment: `super` is a keyword in java

Comment: @Stultuske yes I know that, That's why I wrote "I have to somehow give the Extended class inside the Constructor of Super1" that I can instanciate the subclass instead of the superclass.

Comment: @Jens yes, it was just a mistakenly used example name

Comment: @James Wierzba No that wasn't a typo it actually extends the servlet class, I removed it since it's not that important

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a little too esoteric to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.  Would the following work (it meets the requirements you described I believe)?

```
abstract class Super1 {

    private Class<? extends Super2> super2Type;

    protected Super1(Class<? extends Super2> super2Type) {
        this.super2Type = super2Type;
    }

    abstract doStuff(Class<? extends Super2> super);

    protected doStuffWithDoStuff() {
         Super2 super2 = super2Type.newInstance(); //Error handling omitted for brevity
         doStuff(super2);
         super2.exit();
    }
}
```